# Using If statement in excel to sum cells in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, countif, sumifs

I am currently working with 3 sheets in excel. They are called Sheet1, Sheet2, and Summary. In Sheet1 and Sheet2, I have a list of states with a column for revenue. In the Summary sheet, I want to do an SUMIF statement as if the state in Summary is in Sheet 1 and 2, then I would like to add both revenue amounts together. So if the state of PA was in the Summary page, and it showed up in Sheet1 and Sheet2 then I would like to add both cells together. Now if it showed up in just Sheet1, I would still like to have it add it to the Summary page as it should be just adding a 0 since it is not in Sheet2. Any help with this would be great. I have used COUNTIFs before but I cannot seem to get this to work correctly. Thanks!

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQcJx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed few things here:

**Assumptions:**

Sheet1 has state names in Column C and corresponding revenue in Column D

Sheet2 has state names in Column C and corresponding revenue in Column D

Summary sheet has state name in cell C6 and you want to see the total revenue of states (from sheet1 and sheet 2) in column D of Summary sheet.

To do this use this formula in cell D6 of Summary sheet. You may need to modify the range of table which i assumed "C4:D5". It may be different for you.

```
 =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet1!C4:D5,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet1!C4:D5,2,FALSE))+IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet2!C4:D5,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet2!C4:D5,2,FALSE))
```

Based on more description here is the updated formula:

```
SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$11,Summary!C3,Sheet1!$D$3:$D$11)+SUMIF(‌​Sheet2!$A$3:$B$11,Su‌​mmary!C3,Sheet2!$B$3‌​:$B$11)
```

Comment: Using the VLOOKUP for a test can be costly on processing time, better off using a COUNTIF to check for the existence then the VLOOKUP if it's true.  `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!C4:D5,C6)>0,VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet1!C4:D5,2,0),0)+IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!C4:D5,C6)>0,VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet2!C4:D5,2,0),0)`

Comment: @Dan Donoghue - I was not thinking about the speed. Based on your suggestion i looked around on MSDN and found this function available since excel 2007, called IFERROR. what do you think? shouldn't this be faster?      IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet1!C4:D5,2,FALSE),0)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C6,Sheet2!C4:D5,2,FALSE),0)

Comment: @Anand Thank you for the help. It seems that the amounts are only from Sheet2. The Columns in Sheet1 are as Follows: A=Type, B=State, C=State Name, D=Revenue, E=Credits. Then on Sheet2, the columns are A=State, B=Revenue, C=Revenue. Now on the summary page, The Columns are the same as Sheet1. Also since I want end up adding both amounts together from both Sheets If available, won't I need a SUMIF statement in there or something?

Comment: @goku0650  Based on your explanation you can use sumif formula as below to sum sheet 1 and sheet 2 ranges....                                                                          SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$11,Summary!C3,Sheet1!$D$3:$D$11)+SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$3:$B$11,Summary!C3,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$11)+SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$3:$C$11,Summary!C3,Sheet2!$C$3:$C$11)

Comment: @Anand, Thank you but the results is still just from Sheet1. Should I use a SUMPRODUCT and somehow wrap those SUMIFs inside of it?

Comment: @goku0650 I think it would be helpful if you attach sample table (5-10 rows with dummy values) in your original question from each sheets (e.g. sheet1, sheet2 and summary sheet) and also show what values you are expecting to see in summary sheet (e.g. for state PA value should be 10000, for NY it should be 20000 etc.) and based on that i can modify the answer.

Comment: @Anand, I uploaded an image. The top image is the summary page. Column D is the manual addition of Revenue for Those areas in Sheets VI(Sheet1) and VS(Sheet2). Then Column G is the old script that you had me use which only gave me the amounts in sheet VS. Then Column H is the new script we just used which is only showing the Revenue in sheet VI. So the values I want to see are in Column D for Revenue and Column E for Credits. The script is fine if States in VI are not in VS but if they are, I want both Revenue amounts added together. Then same thing for Credits as well. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should work.... SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$11,Summary!C3,Sheet1!$D$3:$D$11)+SUMIF(‌​Sheet2!$A$3:$B$11,Su‌​mmary!C3,Sheet2!$B$3‌​:$B$11)

Comment: @Anand, Thank you so much for your help. After modifying this last formula, I was able to get the Revenue and Credits to match.

Comment: @Anand it's a moot point now as you have solved for the op but yes iferror could be a very good solution, even better than the countif :)

Comment: @goku0650 please mark it as answered if this addressed your query.